# Change the font of a DatePicker

Tags: swift, xcode

I've been searching for days and I can not see how can i change the font and size of a Datepicker control.

I can change the color by:

```
datePicker.tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

But I can not find how to change the font and its size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not good to Customise the `UIDatePicker`

Although it is suggested to use the Native(Default) `UIDatePicker` of the Swift,

> then also if anyone wants you can refer the following list

Following are some of the Customisable `Datepicker` from GitHub.

1. https://github.com/squimer/DatePickerDialog-iOS-Swift
2. https://github.com/itsmeichigo/DateTimePicker
3. https://github.com/hsylife/SwiftyPickerPopover
4. https://github.com/EngrAhsanAli/AAPickerView
5. https://github.com/dillidon/alerts-and-pickers
6. https://github.com/hughbe/day-date-picker
7. https://github.com/alikaragoz/AIDatePickerController
8. https://github.com/CooperRS/RMDateSelectionViewController
9. https://github.com/zhhlmr/ZHDatePicker
10. https://github.com/GasimGasimzada/FxDatePicker
11. https://github.com/anatoliyv/SMDatePicker
12. https://github.com/MarioIannotta/MIDatePicker

> **Note:** But yes do not Try to customise The appearance of `UIDatePicker`.As it might make a danger of rejection of your app in
>   future.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the links and can they reject the application for that?

Comment: Yes in some case i have known  from some users to be rejected in this case, If it gave u knowledge please do not forget to approve the answer

Comment: My pleasure buddy helping you,Yes do approve the answer with an upvote  to praise us

Answer (score -9):

Use Below Code to change Picker font and size :

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let label = (view as? UILabel) ?? UILabel()
    label.textColor = .black
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont(name: "SanFranciscoText-Light", size: 18)

    // where data is an Array of String
    label.text = pickerData[row]

    return label
}
```

Comment: It is highly recommended that , you read the question properly before answering that, The question is for UIDatePicker and not picker View.

Comment: Kindly find link : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938232/change-the-font-of-a-datepicker/49938606?noredirect=1#comment86895048_49938606

Comment: I need to change font on UIDatepicker not UIPicker

Comment: you can't do it to default UIDatePicker. It may reject App store.